# Run pylint plugin on specific file names only?

Tags: python, pylint

I created a pylint plugin. I want **just this** plugin to only run on modules that have a very specific name. For example, only run the following `UniqueReturnChecker` if the file is named `checkme.py`

```py
class UniqueReturnChecker(BaseChecker):
    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker

    name = 'unique-returns'
    priority = -1

    def visit_return(self, node: nodes.Return) -> None:
        pass

    - - - snipped - - -
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following which is working great:

```py
class UniqueReturnChecker(BaseChecker):
    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker

    name = 'unique-returns'
    priority = -1

    def visit_return(self, node: nodes.Return) -> None:
        import pathlib
        if pathlib.PurePath(node.root().file).name == 'checkme.py':
            # do the check

    - - - snipped - - -
```